# setting Unicode to true using Npgsql provider

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

We can set Unicode=true in connection string when we are using dotConnectFotPostgreSQL.
Is there any way to achieve the same thing if we use NpgSQL provider to insert UTF8 data into PostgreSQL?
As a part of requirement i am using both dotConnectFotPostgreSQl and NpgSQL. Unicode keywork is not supporting by Npgsql and hence my code is failing when i open the connection with NpgSQL.

Criteria: Insert german special characters into PostgreSQL with NpgSQL

ex: Ä   ä   /ɛː/
Ö   ö   /øː/

I am trying to achieve the insertion of above letters into PostgreSQL by using NpgSQL. Unfortunately it is not working.

Database: PostgreSQL 11
npgsql: version 6.0
dotnet framework: 4.6.1

Regards,
Someshwar

Comment: The default encoding is UTF-8, which supports German characters just fine. What's your database collation (you can check that in pg_database)?

Comment: English_united states.1252

Comment: That means that your database *isn't* in UTF-8 or Unicode. You can specify the encoding on the connection string via the Encoding parameter ([docs](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html#misc)).